# How can I generate a random integer in RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, random, android-recyclerview

I need random number in recyclerView adapter but I am unable to get any. I am trying to generate the number in the Activity.java and pass it in the constructor but I am getting same number on every item. I have tried this :

```
                Random random = new Random();
                randInt = random.nextInt(6);
                adapterPost = new AdapterPost(QuestionsActivity.this, postList, randInt);
```

//Adapter

```
public class AdapterPost extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPost.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<ModelPost> postList;
String myUid;
DatabaseReference likesRef;
DatabaseReference postRef;
boolean hasLiked = false;

int randInt;

public AdapterPost(Context context, ArrayList<ModelPost> postList, int randInt) {
    this.context = context;
    this.postList = postList;
    this.randInt = randInt;
    myUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Likes");
    postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

}
```

Please let me know how can I get a different random number on evey item. Thanks!

Comment: can you post adapter source code?

Comment: @Daniel.Wang posted.

Comment: Alright. You need to pass full arraylist of unique random numbers. List's size will be the same of your postList.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code and generate random number in specific range.

```
    int minVal = 50;
    int maxVal = 200;

    Random r = new Random();
    int randomVal = r.nextInt(maxVal - minVal + 1) + minVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create list of unique random numbers having same size which your postList have.

```
 public void generateRandom(){
        Random random = new Random();
        int randInt = random.nextInt(postList.size());
        while(list_rand.size()!=postList.size()) {

            if (list_rand.contains(randInt)) {
                generateRandom();
            } else {
                list_rand.add(randInt);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now call generateRandom method and pass populated list to adapter like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list_rand = new ArrayList(postList.size);
generateRandom()

adapterPost = new AdapterPost(QuestionsActivity.this, postList,list_rand);
```

Now you have unique random numbers according to your listview size. Now you can set items on your listview item freely because every item in list_rand is unique random number.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to generate the number in the Activity.java and pass it in the constructor but I am getting **same number on every item**.

Emphasis mine. Of course you're getting the same number on every item since - based on your code - you are generating *one* random number and using it for the *one* adapter which creates all of your items.

If you want a different number for each item, generate a new number for each item. For example, you could set a random value on each model item before passing it to the adapter.

```
Random random = new Random();
for (item in postList) {
    item.setRandomNumber(random.nextInt(6));
}
adapterPost = new AdapterPost(QuestionsActivity.this, postList);
```